# How many asylum seekers does the UK admit each year?

Tags: asylum

How many asylum seekers does the UK admit each year?

How and where are they housed and how do they support themselves?

How many are refused asylum but are not deported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately there's an excellent recent [Parliamentary briefing note on this subject.](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN01403) The number of applications is between 17,000 and 30,000 per year.

They are forbidden from working, so they are [paid £37.75](https://www.gov.uk/asylum-support/what-youll-get) a week and [assigned housing](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-45082527).

At the end of December 2018, there were 44,258 asylum seekers receiving this support in the UK, of whom 41,309 were living in dispersal accommodation.

It looks like about [half are eventually deported.](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-statistics-october-to-december-2017/how-many-people-are-detained-or-returned)

Comment: Thank you. For how long are they paid and eligible for the house? Are they eligible for the normal range of entitlements?

Comment: What do you mean by the "normal range of entitlements"? I believe the list "what you'll get" is all that asylum seekers are entitled to.

Comment: I mean the entitlements available to a British citizen.

Comment: @Ben it's not clear what further details you need..try reading this http://www.asylumineurope.org/reports/country/united-kingdom/reception-conditions

Comment: @Ben, Asylum seekers are not UK citizens, so are not automatically entitled to many benefits but they do receive free education (if they report they are aged 5-17) and free healthcare plus some maternity benefits. I imagine once granted asylum they cease to be asylum seekers and have access to a greater range of benefits.

Comment: OK. So the entitlements described in this answer are only for the duration of the asylum application, after which they become eligible for the entitlements available to a citizen?

Comment: @Ben, yes, once granted asylum status you get the right to work, a loan to cover rent deposit and work-training, unemployment benefits, pension credits, jobseekers allowance, income support etc. There are the usual conditions for some of these (e.g. have disabilities, be seeking work, etc). https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/asylum-and-refugees/after-you-get-refugee-status/

Comment: @Ben, Yes, but not all the entitlements. Some tax credits are other entitlements are not available. They are also still bound to deportation if they break any serious laws or in any way avail themselves of the protection of their home country. If they want to continue their stay in the UK permanently, they must qualify for ILR, though I believe the fees are waived. If they want citizenship, they have to go through exactly the same procedure as everyone else, fees and all.